# Using LinQ to access multiple tables. What is the correct way to join these tables with LinQ to be the same as SQL Query?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to access all the tables in the data warehouse that I created for an experimental project using Lin-Q and I just don't seem to understand how to access every table regarding the data structure, but can easily query using SQL Server to get my results.  I can access the DimLocation table, but none of the others. I think in the controller is the right approach, but don't know how to select each column of every table using Lin-Q. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My Program: [GlobalCommandCenter](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DP9vY4RdS9LcJJWqDt6G-DtRgKsEnOo2/view)

SQL Query Result Join Tables:

[image]

Tables To Join From Entities Framework:
[image]

LinQ I Created to Join Tables (Need help to join all tables as SQL):
[image]

I can use one table and it works just fine, but I get this error when I try to do multiple tables as Michael describes to do.
[image]

Added multiple joins code in the controller:

```
                LocationDatas = (List<DimLocation>)(from c in entities.DimLocations
                         join f in entities.FactInventories
                         on c.LocationId equals f.LocationId
                         join p in entities.DimProductInventories
                         on f.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                         join dd in entities.DimDates
                         on f.DateSK equals dd.DateSK
                         join dt in entities.DimTimes
                         on f.TimeSK equals dt.TimeSK
                         where c.ContinentName == continent && c.CountryName == country 
                         && c.CountryName == c.CountryName && c.ContinentName == c.ContinentName 
                         && c.ContinentName == continent || string.IsNullOrEmpty(continent) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) 
                         && c.ContinentName == continent
                         select new 
                         {
                             c.LocationId,
                             c.ContinentName,
                             c.CountryName,
                             c.RegionName,
                             c.CityName,
                             p.ProductName,
                             f.ProductPrice,
                             f.ProductQty,
                             dd.StandardDate,
                             dt.StandardTime
                         }),
```

Error I get after adding multiple joins code:
[image]

I edited the call to the model, did away with the bracket and added a semicolon at the very end of it. I then added var to each output with a semi colon at the very end of each statement. After that I get errors on the view.
[image: Error Contoller Problem]
Compilation Error on View (IEnumerable Compatible Error in Razor View?):
[image: Compilation Error on View]

```
public static CommandCenterModel PopulateModel(string continent, string country)
{
    using (GlobalCommandCenter3Entities entities = new GlobalCommandCenter3Entities())
    {
        **CommandCenterModel model = new CommandCenterModel()
        {**
            //Join all the tables together and extract the information into one web grid. 
            LocationDatas = (from c in entities.DimLocations
                             join f in entities.FactInventories
                             on c.LocationId equals f.LocationId
                            
                             join p in entities.DimProductInventories
                             on f.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                             
                             join dd in entities.DimDates
                             on f.DateSK equals dd.DateSK

                             join dt in entities.DimTimes
                             on f.TimeSK equals dt.TimeSK
                             where c.ContinentName == continent && c.CountryName == country && c.CountryName == c.CountryName 
                             && c.ContinentName == c.ContinentName && c.ContinentName == continent || string.IsNullOrEmpty(continent) 
                             || string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) && c.ContinentName == continent
                             select  c).ToList(),    

            Country = (from c in entities.DimLocations
                       orderby c.CountryName
                       where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.CountryName) && c.CountryName != null && continent == c.ContinentName
                       select new SelectListItem { Text = c.CountryName, Value = c.CountryName }).Distinct().ToList(),
 

            Continent = (from c in entities.DimLocations
                                 orderby c.ContinentName
                                 where (c.ContinentName == c.ContinentName)
                                 select new SelectListItem { Text = c.ContinentName, Value = c.ContinentName }).Distinct().ToList(),
            /*
            Location = (from c in entities.DimLocations
                             join f in entities.FactInventories
                             on c.LocationId equals f.LocationId
                             join p in entities.DimProductInventories
                             on f.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                             join dd in entities.DimDates
                             on f.DateSK equals dd.DateSK
                             join dt in entities.DimTimes
                             on f.TimeSK equals dt.TimeSK
                             where c.ContinentName == continent && c.CountryName == country && c.CountryName == c.CountryName && c.ContinentName == c.ContinentName && c.ContinentName == continent || string.IsNullOrEmpty(continent) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) && c.ContinentName == continent
                             select new { c.ContinentName, c.CountryName, c.RegionName, c.CityName, f.ProductPrice, f.ProductQty, dd.StandardDate, dt.StandardTime }).ToList(),
            */

        };
        //Allow to stay on selection. 
        model.SectionCity = continent;
        return model;
    }
}
```

SQL Query:

```
    SELECT ContinentName, CountryName, RegionName, CityName, ProductName, 
    finv.ProductPrice, 
    finv.ProductQty, StandardDate, StandardTime 
    FROM DimLocation dloc
    INNER JOIN FactInventory finv ON finv.LocationId = dloc.LocationId
    INNER JOIN DimProductInventory dprod ON finv.ProductId = dprod.ProductId
    INNER JOIN DimDate ddat ON finv.DateSK = ddat.DateSK
    INNER JOIN DimTime dtim ON finv.TimeSK = dtim.TimeSK


                SELECT * FROM FactInventory   
                SELECT * FROM DimLocation
                SELECT * FROM DimDate            
                SELECT * FROM DimTime
                SELECT * FROM DimProductInventory
```

Controller:

```
    using ClassLibraryDAL.DAL;
    using OperationsCommandCenter.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace OperationsCommandCenter.Controllers
   {
    public class HomeController : Controller
   {
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CommandCenterModel model = PopulateModel(null, null);

        return View(model);
    }

    //Controls DropDownList.
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string continent, string country)
    {
        CommandCenterModel model = PopulateModel(continent, country);

        return View(model);
    }

    //Population Controller. References list selection.
    public static CommandCenterModel PopulateModel(string continent, string country)
    {
        using (GlobalCommandCenter3Entities entities = new 
        GlobalCommandCenter3Entities())
        {
            CommandCenterModel model = new CommandCenterModel()
            {
                //Join all the tables together and extract the information into one web 
                  grid. 
                LocationDatas = (from c in entities.DimLocations
                                 join f in entities.FactInventories
                                 on c.LocationId equals f.LocationId
                                 
                                 join p in entities.DimProductInventories
                                 on f.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                                 
                                 join dd in entities.DimDates
                                 on f.DateSK equals dd.DateSK

                                 join dt in entities.DimTimes
                                 on f.TimeSK equals dt.TimeSK
                                 where c.ContinentName == continent && c.CountryName == 
        country && c.CountryName == c.CountryName && c.ContinentName == c.ContinentName 
        && c.ContinentName == continent || string.IsNullOrEmpty(continent) || 
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) && c.ContinentName == continent
                                 select  c).ToList(),  

                Country = (from c in entities.DimLocations
                           orderby c.CountryName
                           where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.CountryName) && c.CountryName 
         != null && continent == c.ContinentName
                           select new SelectListItem { Text = c.CountryName, Value = 
                           c.CountryName }).Distinct().ToList(),


                Continent = (from c in entities.DimLocations
                                     orderby c.ContinentName
                                     where (c.ContinentName == c.ContinentName)
                                     select new SelectListItem { Text = c.ContinentName, 
                                     Value = c.ContinentName }).Distinct().ToList(),
                /*
                Location = (from c in entities.DimLocations
                                 join f in entities.FactInventories
                                 on c.LocationId equals f.LocationId
                                 join p in entities.DimProductInventories
                                 on f.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                                 join dd in entities.DimDates
                                 on f.DateSK equals dd.DateSK
                                 join dt in entities.DimTimes
                                 on f.TimeSK equals dt.TimeSK
                                 where c.ContinentName == continent && c.CountryName == 
       country && c.CountryName == c.CountryName && c.ContinentName == c.ContinentName 
      && c.ContinentName == continent || string.IsNullOrEmpty(continent) || 
      string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) && c.ContinentName == continent
                                 select new { c.ContinentName, c.CountryName, 
       c.RegionName, c.CityName, f.ProductPrice, f.ProductQty, dd.StandardDate, 
       dt.StandardTime }).ToList(),
                */

            };
            //Allow to stay on selection. 
            model.SectionCity = continent;
            return model;
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Model:

```
   using ClassLibraryDAL.DAL;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.Mvc;

   namespace OperationsCommandCenter.Models
   {
   public class CommandCenterModel
   {
    public List<DimLocation> LocationDatas { get; set; }
    public List<DimProductInventory> ProductInventory { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Country { get; set; } 
    public List<SelectListItem> Continent { get; set; } 

    public List<SelectListItem> ProductName { get; set; } 

    //public List<DimLocation> Location { get; set; }

    public string SectionCity { get; set; }

}
}
```

View:

```
  @model  OperationsCommandCenter.Models.CommandCenterModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
string Country = Model.Country.ToString();
string SectionCity = Model.SectionCity;

 WebGrid webGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model.LocationDatas, canPage: true, canSort: 
   true, sortDirectionFieldName: "ContinentName, CountryName, RegionName, CityName", 
   rowsPerPage: 20);
webGrid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<title>Global Command Center</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/YardDogStyle.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
/>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js")" rel="stylesheet" 
 type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 />

<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/YardDogStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  </head>
  <body>
<div id="time"></div>
<div id="RowCount"></div>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">

    function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
    }
    function startTime() {
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();

        // add a zero in front of numbers<10
        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s; //Get the 
        time.
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "Date: " + today; //Get the Date.
        t = setTimeout(function () {
            startTime()
        }, 500);
    }
    startTime();
</SCRIPT>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ScrollableGridPlugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=webGrid.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
            ScrollHeight: 300
        });
        $('#<%=webGrid.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
            ScrollHeight: 300
        });
    });
</script>

<script src="Scripts/ScrollableGridPlugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ScrollableGridPlugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=webGrid.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
            ScrollHeight: 300,
            Width: 467
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Count the rows on the webGrid that are visible... is my intent with this code.
    function CountRows() {
        var totalRowCount = 0;
        var rowCount = 0;
        var gridView = document.getElementById("<%=webGrid.ClientID %>");
        var rows = gridView.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            totalRowCount++;
            if (rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length > 0) {
                rowCount++;

            }

        }
        var message = "Total Row Count: " + totalRowCount;
        message += "\nRow Count: " + rowCount;
        //alert(message);
        message = document.getElementById('RowCount').innerHTML = message;

        // return false;

    }
    CountRows();
</script>
<form id="formYardDog" class="formYardDog" runat="server" method="post">

    @{ int firstRecord = (webGrid.PageIndex * webGrid.RowsPerPage) + 1;
        int lastRecord = (webGrid.PageIndex * webGrid.RowsPerPage) + webGrid.Rows.Count;

        // webGrid.Rows..GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible);
    }
    <div id="RowCountTop"><b>Records: @firstRecord - @lastRecord of 
    @webGrid.TotalRowCount</b></div><br />

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "formYardDog" 
    }))
    {
        //Loop to Get Dictionary List Buttons with Distinct Section Values.
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Continent.Count; i++)
        {
         
            //If the SectionCity is not null, then back-ground color to red.

            if (@Model.Continent[i].Value == SectionCity)
            {

                <button name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Continent)" 
         value="@Model.Continent[i].Value" id="ddlSectionButtons" runat="server" , new { 
        class="ddlSectionButtons" onClick="focusMe(this);" style="background-color: 
       #AFE1AF; color: black" }>@Model.Continent[i].Value</button>

            }
            else
            {
                // var Count = i;
                <!--  <input type="submit" name="Html.NameFor(model => model.Section)" 
       value=Model.Section[i].Value id="ddlSectionButtons" , new { 
     class="ddlSectionButtons" onClick="focusMe(this);" }/> -->
                <button name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Continent)" 
    value="@Model.Continent[i].Value" id="ddlSectionButtons" runat="server" , new { 
       class="ddlSectionButtons" onClick="focusMe(this);" 
      }>@Model.Continent[i].Value</button>

            }

        }
        if (SectionCity == null || SectionCity == "")
        {
            <button text="All" type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(model => 
     model.Continent)" , new { onClick="focusMe(this);" id="ddlSectionAllButton" 
   class="ddlSectionAllButton" placeholder="All" style="background-color: #AFE1AF; 
      color: black" })>All</button>
        }
        else
        {
            <button text="All" type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(model => 
    model.Continent)" , new { onClick="focusMe(this);" id="ddlSectionAllButton" 
     class="ddlSectionButtons" placeholder="All" style="background-color: #045AC6; 
      color: white" })>All</button>
        }


        <br />
        //Section == Country    //ContinentLocation == PlantLocation
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Continent, Model.Continent, "- Continent - 
      ", new { onchange = "document.forms[0].submit();", @id = "ddlWarehouses", @class = 
      "ddlWarehouses" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, Model.Country, " - Country -", new 
      { onchange = "document.forms[0].submit();", @id = "ddlSection", @class = 
      "ddlSection" })

        <div id="content">
            @webGrid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
                                headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                                footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                     //alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                     selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
                                rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
                                  mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                      htmlAttributes: new { @id = "webGrid" },
                     columns: webGrid.Columns(
                     webGrid.Column(header: "Actions", format:@<span class="link">
<a href="#" class="collapse expand-btn">Expand</a>
<a href="#" class="expand collapse-btn">Collapse</a>
<!--
<a class="Edit" href="javascript:;">Edit</a>
<a class="Clear" href="javascript:;">Clear</a>
<a class="Update" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Update</a>
<a class="Cancel" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Cancel</a>
    -->
 </span>),

   webGrid.Column(columnName: "Country", header: "Country", format: @<div>
            <label id="ContinentLbl" class="label"><a id="CountryNameLnk" 
    href="javascript:;">@item.ContinentName</a></label>
            <!--- <input id="Location" class="text" type="text" value="item.CountryName" 
     style="display:none" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"/> -->
            <br />
            <label id="CountryLbl" ><a id="RegioNameLnk" href="#" class="collapse 
  expand-btn" >@item.CountryName</a></label>
            <br />
            <label id="RegionLbl"  ><a id="CityNameLnk"href="#" class="collapse expand- 
   btn" >@item.RegionName</a></label>
            <br />
            <label id="CityLbl" class="expand collapse" >@item.CityName</label>
        </div>, style: "CountryName"),

   webGrid.Column(header: "RowPageID", format: @<div>
  <label id="LocationIDLbl" class="label">@item.LocationID</label>
 </div>, style: "LocationID"))),

            <div id="RowCountBpttom"><b>Records: @firstRecord - @lastRecord of 
   @webGrid.TotalRowCount</b></div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="WebGridTable">
        </div>
    }
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="https://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/YardDog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Expand the Nodes. 
    $(function () {
        $('.expand').hide();      // Default - hide the table row of Course information
        // and also hide the Collapse text from
        // Student information's action column

        $('.expand-btn, .collapse-btn').on("click", function () {
            var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
            tr.find('.expand, .collapse').toggle();    // toggle to display either 
  Expand or
            // Collapse text in the Student row

            tr.next().toggle();    // toggle to display table row with Course 
 information
        });
    });
</script>


  </body>
```

Comment: do you need to get a joined projection with ContinentName, CountryName, RegionName, CityName, ProductName, finv.ProductPrice, finv.ProductQty, StandardDate, StandardTime fields?

Comment: Yes, I am writing out to a web grid and need to show Product in another column of the same web grid. The controller uses LinQ, but I don't know how to access the other tables using the same LinQ Query.

Comment: (saw note to @Michael)
A collection is an IEnumerable, no? FWIW, your link to your program is not working. Mind you, in LINQ (it is LINQ or Linq not Lin-q), if your database have proper relations (from diagram it looks like it has), then you wouldn't need joins at all. Tools create "navigation properties" for you and you simply use dot notation to access "relations".

Comment: Can you give me an idea Cetin on how to use dot notation to access relations? I have all the relationships set up on the tables just fine in a Star Schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a custom projection as a result of the query you can either select it to an anonymous class or create another DTO for this.

Trimmed example (due to your code being a screenshot - I can't copy it):

```cs
var customProjection = from c in entities.DimLocations
                       join f in entities.FactInventories
                       on c.LocationId equals f.LocationId
                       select new {
                           c.ContinentName,
                           f.ProductPrice
                       }
```

This way you can access fields from different tables.

Comment: It won't allow me to do:  select new {
                                           c.ContinentName,
                                           f.ProductPrice
                                           }

Comment: compiler gives you an error or some kind of runtime exception?

Comment: I know that your query is correct, but it won't work on the method as expected. It works with one table, but I cannot join multiple tables for some reason that it won't work. I put a link to my program so that you can download it and change the code, show me where I am going wrong with the code???

Comment: I think I am beginning to understand, I don't have IEnumerable being used in the View, but a generic collections instead and when you want to do multiple joins, you need IEnumerable? This seems to be the way to solve this from what I am thinking. It works fine with just one table, but multiple joins won't work! Any help would be greatly appreciated!